# installing the Lubuntu 13.10 elementary Lubuntu icon set in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, icons

I noticed the 13.10 elementary Lubuntu icon set is missing from Lubuntu 14.04. Is there a way to re-install the 13.10 elementary icon set in Lubuntu 14.04? It was installed by default in 13.10. I am not sure where to find that specific icon set.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The package you are looking for is elementary-icon-theme.
You can find it in synaptic package manager or just install it straight from the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install elementary-icon-theme
```

(They happen to be my preferred icons in Lubuntu too).